# Why does PyAutoGUI freeze when calling `size`?

Tags: python

I'm trying to test a single line of PyAutoGUI but it gets stuck as soon as the `size` method is called.

```
import pyautogui
print("Library imported")
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
print("Measurements taken")
pyautogui.moveTo(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2)
print("Cursor moved")
```

The terminal didn't print "Measurements taken" and would not terminate the process. I found this error in the console log:

```
31/03/2015 15:57:30.000 kernel[0]: process Python[2574] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 822; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 45377
```

I ran a tracer to see where it was getting stuck, and apparently the last line the process reads is:

```
pyautogui/__init__.py:122   line          return platformModule._size()
```

The program does not go past [calling `platformModule._size()` in the library](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/__init__.py).

My environment is OSX Yosemite and I have installed pyobjc and pyobjc-core.